# Get random password in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a course and one of the tasks is to generate four different passwords that should fill the four different paragraphs `<p id="first"></p>`, `<p id="second"></p>`, `<p id="third"></p>`, `<p id="fourth"></p>`

I have created a script that creates a password but somehow it doesn't print the first password. When I do `console.log(password)` it shows that creates a password on the console. But when I try to put `first.textContent = password` it shows nothing.

```js
let chars = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
let number = 10
let password = ""
let first = document.getElementById("first")
let second = document.getElementById("second")
let third = document.getElementById("third")
let fourth = document.getElementById("fourth")

function generate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    let passwordChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
    password += chars[passwordChar]
    return password
  }
}
first.textContent = password
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Generate a random password</h1>
  <p id="description">Never use an insecure password again</p>
  <button onclick="generate()">Generate passwords</button>
  <p id="line"></p>
  <p id="first"></p>
  <p id="second"></p>
  <p id="third"></p>
  <p id="fourth"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm also stuck to generate each time the function is running a new password and put it on the next paragraph. Like so:

```
first.textContent = password
second.textContent = password
third.textContent = password
fourth.textContent = password
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The `generate()` function is called when clicking on the button. Changed the numbers into chars. No effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing going wrong is that `first.textContent = password` is placed outside of `generate()`, so it will be set to the initial `password` value (empty string), but is never updated.

Without changing too much, I suggest splitting the code into two functions. One to generate a password, and one that assigns element contents to these randomly generated passwords.

```js
function generatePassword() {
  const chars = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "A", "B", "C", "D"];
  let password = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const passwordChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    password += chars[passwordChar];
  }
  // I've moved the return down, because you return after generating only 1 character
  return password;
}

function loadPasswords() {  
  document.getElementById("first").textContent = generatePassword();
  document.getElementById("second").textContent = generatePassword();
  document.getElementById("third").textContent = generatePassword();
  document.getElementById("fourth").textContent = generatePassword();
}
```

```html
<h1>Generate a random password</h1>
<p id="description">Never use an insecure password again</p>
<button onclick="loadPasswords()">Generate passwords</button>
<p id="line"></p>
<p id="first"></p>
<p id="second"></p>
<p id="third"></p>
<p id="fourth"></p>
```

Like already stated by other answers, I would personally avoid using inline handlers and use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps me a lot to understand better Javascript. Is still a long way but appreciate the time you've taken to show me the way!

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to every single line of code you write. Every single line has a meaning!

1. You don't need to keep track of the 'password' in an outer scope variable. You just need a local variable (also note the `return` part should be after the `for` loop:

```
function generate() {
    let pw = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        let passwordChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
        pw += chars[passwordChar]
    }    
    return pw
}
```

2. You are not calling the `generate()`:

```
first.textContent = generate()
second.textContent = generate()
third.textContent = generate()
fourth.textContent = generate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I'm calling the generate function when clicking on the button

Comment: If such, you  are setting the `first.textContent` before calling a `generate()` beforehand

Comment: So it is calling before it is called with the button? If so, how do I change this? Appreciate

Comment: When I change to your code I get `!ReferenceError: pw is not defined`. when I write `let pw = ''` out of the function it works

Answer (score 0):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers.

Here is a snippet using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). For retrieving and filling certain elements, use a single identifier for them (here: a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)). Now you can loop the elements and fill them with your password values ([forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). In this snippet the passwords are generated using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

[See also...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7p9d8r?file=index.js)

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
// ↓ only do things if button#passGen is clicked
  if (evt.target.id === `passGen`) {
    return generate();
  }
}

function generate() {
  const chars = `0123456789abcdefghijk`;
  document.querySelectorAll(`[data-passgenerated]`)
  //                         ↑ retrieve all p[data-passgenerated]
  // ↓ Loop through the elements and fill them
  .forEach(elem =>  elem.textContent = [...Array(10)].map(v => 
    chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)]).join(``)
);
}
```

```html
<p data-passgenerated="1"></p>
<p data-passgenerated="2"></p>
<p data-passgenerated="3"></p>
<p data-passgenerated="4"></p>
<button id="passGen">Create passwords</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! But I have to try to make it with the basic knowledge they have given to us on the course. We haven't done the code that you provide. Anyway, really appreciate